# JGR Deducer's Data Viewer, Editing Data and Variables - Undo Function?

Tags: r

Thank for reading - I'm asking a question, for which I think the answer is already no.  But perhaps you might have suggestions that I haven't thought of.

In using JGR and Deducer for editing data, you can easily edit a cell by clicking and writing in something new, but is there any way to Undo what you have done?  Furthermore, in editing variables, say for instance, I have a variable of 5 factors, and I delete one factor using the data viewer window, selecting the factor and hitting the minus sign.  Is there then any way to get the variable back, short of reloading the data?

If you need clarification, just let me know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, the answer is no.